# HTTPGet With Multiple Fields To Get Data From Database

Tags: c#, mysql, postman, asp.net-core-webapi, http-get

I have a database that contains students. To get the students by their Id used a HTTP Get, here is a snip it of my action method:

```
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "Get")]
 public Student Get(int id)
{
     DataSet data = objDB.GetDataSet("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Id = " + id.ToString());
}
```

Now I want to create another HTTP Get that can get the students by their last name and grade that they are in. In my database I have a field for last name and grade just like id. But I'm having trouble checking them both at once. I'm later going to have 2 textboxes where the user can enter a last name and a grade and all students that match the last name and grade entered will be displayed. Here is my code so far: (lastname & grade are varchar in my database)

```
[HttpGet("{lastname}/{grade}", Name = "GetLastNameGrade")]
public Student Get (string lastname, string grade)
{
DataSet ds = objDB.GetDataSet("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE LastName = " + lastname.ToString() + "AND" + "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Grade = " + grade.ToString());

}
```

Here is my Student class

```
public int StudentID { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string Grade { get; set; }
```

I'm having trouble with the SQL statement for last name and grade. When I try to run in the method in Postman I'm not getting anything displayed. I'm confused on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Wrap `lastname.ToString()` and the other one with single quotes.  `= '" + lastname.ToString() + "' AND ...` Better yet, you should use parameterized queries. Better yet use an ORM tool, EF, Dapper, wahtever.

Comment: I'm not sure what  ORM tool, EF, Dapper are, I just started to learn how to make my own Web API and contacting my database. Is this what you meant though:  "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE LastName = " + 'lastname.ToString()' + "AND" + "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Grade = " + 'grade.ToString()');? @OguzOzgul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sake of having formatted code;

```
DataSet ds = objDB.GetDataSet("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE LastName = '" + lastname.ToString() + "' AND Grade = '" + grade.ToString() + "'");
```

Which will produce a valid Sql statement like

```
SELECT * FROM Students WHERE LastName = 'OZGUL' AND Grade = 'B+'
```

Comment: Can you please explain why those ' are needed versus " " ?

Comment: Because SQL standard uses single quotes for string content. When you write like LastName = " + lastName.ToString() it is converted to LastName = Oguz SQL statement which is invalid. You can do this for numeric types, but not for char types (char, nchar, varchar, nvarchar)

Comment: If I also wanted to get them by gender would it be DataSet ds = objDB.GetDataSet("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Gender = ' " + gender.ToString()'); ? I'm not sure if the OR part to only get the male students or female students would go inside the ' quotes. @OguzOzgul

Comment: Whatever is char, varchar etc, should go between single quotes. For boolean types (Sql data type BIT) use 1 or 0. If Gender is char(1) (F or M), use single quotes like "WHERE Gender = '" + gender.ToString() + "'"

Comment: I have some prefilled students in my database and gender is a varchar, so it would go between single quotes then. But I'm not sure how I would check for male for female would this be the correct way? DataSet ds = objDB.GetDataSet("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Gender = 'Female' OR 'Male ' " + gender.ToString()');? @newtosvelte

Comment: If the values in your database for the gendere column are 'Female' and 'Male', then, yes, you should select like that. Is this MS Sql Server? You can use the Sql Server Management Studio to practice and test SQL Statements

Comment: Ah wait, you should write : objDB.GetDataSet("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Gender = '" + gender.ToString() + "'");

Comment: I'm testing my methods in Postman and the way I test it for last name and grade was the url I get when I run my WebAPI then /Bob/B. So for gender I would try /Female or /Male, but if you write the statement like that how would the statement be checking the database has Male or Female for the gender category? @OguzOzgul

Comment: Routing is something you should handle, correct. Can you do your routing for gender like `[HttpGet("gender/{gender}", Name = "GetByGender")]` ?

Comment: Yes I could change the routing to anything I want but the part I'm confused about is when I test the method. If I only want female students to show up when I run the method, I'm not sure what I would write to only display females. So if I had this route, https://localhost:00000/api/Student/female, I'm confused on what I would need to add to the SQL statement to get only females or only get males. @OguzOzgul

Comment: What values does your database have? Student/female will run your method, female can be the value (if your database contains "female" and "male" in its records for the gender column

Comment: Yes that exactly what I have, I have a column for gender and inside I just have Male or Female. So would it be ("SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Gender = '" + gender.ToString() + "AND Value = 'Female' OR 'Male''");? @OguzOzgul

Comment: No, it will be SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Gender = '" + gender.ToString() + "'" that's all

Comment: This statement works but is only showing 1 male or 1 female when I run my get method, isn't it supposed to show all male and females because I put SELECT * and the * means all? I'm confused @OguzOzgul

Comment: Like I wrote https://localhost:0000000/api/Student/Female and same with Male and am only getting 1 male out the 15 I have, so it kind of works but isn't showing all males an all females

Comment: * means all fields. Select returns all the Records but you Need to iterate over them. Please post all your controller code and let me help

Comment: I was able to figure it out thanks for your help thus far, much appriciated! @OguzOzgul